# loading radiogroups from sqlite database

Tags: android

I can't seem to get my radiogroups to populate based on the below code.  Once my cursor runs against the database I get the below output:

```
Cursor data = db.getReadableDatabase().query(db.myTable, myColumns, db.USERID + "= ?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(user1)}, null, null, null);

    data.moveToPosition(position);
    checkx = data.getInt(data.getColumnIndex(db.VALUE));
    Log.d("checkedid", "checkedid: " + checkx);

1
1
1
1
1
```

Based on this I need the first radiobutton to be checked each time.  Here is my current switch statement, but nothing gets checked.

```
if(checkx > 0) {

        switch (checkx) {
            case 1:
                group.check(R.id.a1);
                break;
            case 2:
                group.check(R.id.a2);
                break;
            case 3:
                group.check(R.id.a3);
                break;
            case 4:
                group.check(R.id.a4);
                break;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Store the checked RadioButton "index" as an int: 0, 1, 2, ... Then retrieve this value and use a `switch case` to set the corresponding RadioButton as checked, as in @Tauqir's answer.

Answer (score 1):

programmatically, you can use the setChecked method defined in the checkable interface:

```
if(checkx > 0) {

    switch (checkx) {
        case 1:
            RadioButton b1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.option1);
            b1.setChecked(true);
            break;
        case 2:
            RadioButton b2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.option2);
            b2.setChecked(true);
            break;
--------- etc------------

}
```

Comment: tried the above already...still nothing gets checked on load.